# Ubuntu 22.04 screen keyboard only works sometimes

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

i have lenovo idea pad duet 3 10igl5, its a touch screen detachable laptop, for some reason when using the touchscreen mode, the on screen only shows up in the Ubuntu UI but not in the browser apps

Comment: I have the same problem, but with a ThinkBook 14s Yoga. My workaround is to activate the screen keyboard in the accessibility settings, so that it is also there when I use a mouse, but at least I can still operate everything with touch.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The on screen keyboard is turned on. Is there a manual way to open the keyboard? Swipe up from the bottom no longer works.